# Adding event to a dynamically added control added via an event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

From what I understand the best time to add a control to a page is in the OnInit event. but if you add a control via another controls event you don't have a choice it's event going to get add after the load event.

For example:

```
Private Sub catalog_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    p1.Controls.Add(New blah)
End Sub

Public Class blah
    Inherits Control

    Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(e As EventArgs)
        Debug.WriteLine("- control oninit")
        MyBase.OnInit(e)
        Dim b As Button = New Button
        b.Text = "link to me"
        AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf blah2
        Me.Controls.Add(b)

    End Sub
    Sub blah2(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Debug.WriteLine("* button event fires")
        Dim b As Button = New Button
        b.Text = "another button!"
        AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf blah2
        Me.Controls.Add(b)

    End Sub
End Class
```

How do I get the second button's event to fire?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Sorry added at the end

Comment: read up on the [asp.net web forms lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) very carefully, and ask yourself if this is the road you want to go down. Easiest thing is to either have all the controls you need and set visibility, or if it is dealing with data, use a DataRepeater, or grid to load up a dynamic series of UI events.

Comment: I have read the document already and it still doesn't answer my question. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#Anchor_3) talks about the catch-up events. Is this where I should be looking at?

Comment: may I ask what larger problem you are trying to solve? there may be an easier way to do what you are after.